# How do I have Inno Setup update multiple locations?

Tags: inno-setup, directory

I have an application that uses Inno Setup as its installer.
I am now writing an updater using Inno Setup to apply some updates to various installed locations.

This application can be installed on removable flash drives as a portable app and I would like to be able to roll out the updates across several drives/locations/directories for each drive attached to the PC at once.

Is there a way to get Inno Setup to roll out its contents as an update to each location in an array of locations?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly.    One option is to build an install for the files that is designed to be silent.

Then write a second install that compiles that uses the first one.     Then you `[Code]` Section you could call `ShellExecute()` executing the first installer.   You could call the first installer as many times as you wanted.

Although, I suspect this may really creates havok on the Add/Remove Programs.